# Record screen from inside the android app on kitkat creates an empty movie

Tags: android

I tried doing this

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 --time-limit 30 /sdcard/xyz.mp4");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

but the size of the video was 0 bytes after the recording

Comment: This is not permitted.  ADB's shell user has permission to do this, but the unix users apps run as do not, and by design cannot obtain it.

Comment: any other way to do this?

Comment: Not on official Android releases, though probably on some alternate ROMs.

Comment: If it's only your own app you want to record (which would have been a lot clearer if Andrew hadn't shut down you original, quite reasonable question), you may be able to obtain the data from the View itself and save that in same way.  Another option could be to save a record of game's own UI update operations, and render that to video using another instance of the game's rendering engine on a server somewhere.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any work around?